# Convert categorical rows to column header with string values (no aggregation)

Tags: python, pivot, reshape, transpose

I would like to transform my categorical rows to columns, without any aggregation. I have tried it with pivot but I get NANs.

This is the data frame:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'Art':['blue', 'red', 'blue', 'red', 'blue', 'red', 'blue', 'red'],

'Description':['Some text 1', 'Some text 2', 'Some text 3', 'Some text 4', 'Some text 5', 'Some text 6', 'Some text 7', 'Some text 8']})
```

When I try to pivot:

`data.pivot(columns='Art')`

I get:

[image: This as output]

And I have solved the NAN problem like this:

`data.pivot(columns='Art').apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values))`

This is the desired outcome:

[image: desired outcome]

However, I would like to know if there is a smarter way to simply get my classes as column headers.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

your solution already seems pretty clear and concise.. with one line you have the result:

```
data.pivot(columns='Art').apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values))
```